# Excel formula to copy cell value without keeping reference to source cell

Tags: excel-formula

In my excel sheet, I need to copy the value of a cell A1 to another cell B1. When I change the value in cell A1, B1 should keep its original value.

Basically what would happen if you copy > paste special > Values
However, I cannot do this manually with mouse or keyboard input. I also cannot use macros/VBA.

Does a formula exist in excel that accomplishes this same task?
I tried playing around with =VALUE(A1) and =concat(A1) but these formulas all contain references to cell A1 and the result changes as soon the value in A1 changes.

Comment: What you are asking cannot be done with built-in excel formulas.

Comment: Also, since you want B1 to be independent from A1, when do you want B1 to update then? What do you want the trigger to be if not manual?

Comment: The idea is that ultimately there is some trigger condition that specifies if values in B1 gets updated. But it sounds that it is unfortunately not possible using formulas.

Comment: Actually, that can be done, but it comes with an error message, because you have to have the cell to refer to itself.

Comment: And you would also not be able to conduct further calculations on that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, what you are asking can be done but at the cost of an error message and without the possibility of further calculations of the 'copied' cell, by letting the 'copying' cell refer to itself.

[image: Example Screenshot 1]

As shown in the screenshot above, the value returned in F3 is the value of E3 or itself, depending on the selection in F5.

Selecting "No" (or anything else but "Yes") in F5 and thereby having F3 refer to itself will show an error message, but the value it had will stay, even when saved and closed. However, no further calculation can be conducted on that cell:

[image: Example Screenshot 2]

Lastly, this solution is probably unstable.